# Waiting in GameMaker: Studio

Tags: wait, gml

I composed a script in GML that is supposed to wait a few seconds before executing a script, but I tried it out, and it isn't working. Can someone help? And I don't want to use the wait/sleep function, since that delays everything in the room. Here my script is.

```
//Rename this script according to what you want to wait for
//Here is how many seconds we want to wait.
var seconds = 0;
//We will multiply the amount of seconds by the room speed, and store it in a variable
var waittime = seconds * room_speed;
//Then, we will define a script for later
var script = "Your Script here";
//Then, we will add a question, and it will ask if the room speed is the same as the wait time
if (room_speed == waittime or room_speed > waittime) {
    //Then, if the amount of room speed is the same as the wait time, then execute the script
    script_execute(script);
}
else {
    //But if the amount of seconds is not equal, or greater than the wait time, then just add the fps to the wait time-
    waittime += fps;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The sleep function has been removed from GameMaker: Studio as far as I know. You can make your own timer script by using alarms:

In your trigger/pause script:

```
instance_deactivate_all(true);
alarm[0] = 60 //Your time in frames. If your room_speed is 60, this will be one second.
```

Then in the Alarm 0 Event you can do something like:

```
instance_reactivate_all();
```

Although this will stop rendering any objects you may currently have on screen.
Your other bet is to make a `global.timer = 60` and stop the step event of every object `if(global.timer > 0)` and then have something like a director object to run `if(global.timer > 0) global.timer--;`

Sadly there is no easy way of doing this any more, but hopefully these two methods will suffice.

Comment: Okay, but I want to know if my script will work. I want to wait only 1 object, not all of them. My best bet is to go with the other one, and I can add a seconds variable, and then multiply it by the room speed to create the global timer. Then I can use the second script, and modify it to make a fading in animation.

Comment: In this case, you could selectively put the if statement in the objects you want paused. Any object that does not check for the global timer will continue to execute as normal.